# defining lambda expressions

Tags: data-structures, lambda-calculus

I am studying for my exam and I wanted to do some extra excercises, but I have some problems with solving :) Can anyone please help or give me some advice where to start? Thank you!

We can represent every list of lambda expressions **$x_0, x_1, ..., x_k$** with lambda expression **$[x_0, x_1, ..., x_k]$** , defined as:
**$[x_0, x_1, ... , x_k] = \lambda c n. c \, x_0 \, (c \, x_1 \, (... (c \, x_k \, n) ...))$**

Define lambda expression s, satisfying the equation  **$s([\underline{n_0}, ..., \underline{n_k}]) = \underline{n_0 + ... + n_k}$** , where  **$\underline{n}$** is a Church numeral, representing natural number **$n$**.

Define lambda expression **$r$** , satisfying the equation  **$r([x_0, ..., x_k]) = [x_k,  ..., x_0]$** .

Define lambda expression **$h$** and **$t$** , satisfying the equation  **$h([x_0, ..., x_k]) = x_0 in t([x_0, x_1, ..., x_k]) = [x_1, ..., x_k]$** .

Comment: Actually I don't know where to start, because I am not sure if I understand what I have to do. I don't understand if at the beginning we get the list, or we have to calculate the numbers from expression given. Also, I know how to define sum for example, but I don't know how to get first element from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This way lists are represented as [folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_on_lists). So if you have a lambda term representing a list, you just supply a folding function and a value to start with and the result will be the folded value.